# Integration of sqrt(f(x)) dx

Tags: integration, derivatives

Every method I try, leads to a more complicated situation or back somewhere along the path. Here is the expression:

$$\int\sqrt\frac{a\pi+x}{a(a\pi-x)}dx$$

What is the solution for this? is there any?

[updates]

I. U-substitution:
$$\int\sqrt\frac{a\pi+x}{a(a\pi-x)}dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt a}\int f(u)u'dx$$
where $u=\frac{a\pi+x}{a\pi-x}$ AND $f(u)=u^{1/2}$

II. Integration by parts

$$\int\sqrt\frac{a\pi+x}{a(a\pi-x)}dx = 1/\sqrt a\int f(x)g'(x) dx$$
where $f(x)=\sqrt{a\pi+x}$ AND $g'(x)=(\sqrt {a\pi-x})^{-1}$

$$g(x)=-2(\sqrt{a\pi-x})$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+a\pi}}$$
$$so:$$ $$\frac{1}{\sqrt a}\int \sqrt\frac{a\pi+x}{a\pi-x} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt a} \biggl(-2\sqrt{(a\pi)^2-x^2}+\int \sqrt\frac{a\pi-x}{a\pi+x} dx \biggr)$$

In this case, it looks like we are half the way to get back from where we've started...

Comment: What techniques have you tried?

Comment: The most obvious thing to point out is that $2-1=1$, for what it's worth.

Comment: now that is aaa... simplification... I got no explanation

Comment: Clayton, basic u-substitution. For $g(x) =  \frac{a\pi+x}{a(a\pi-x)}$ and f(x) as $g^\frac{1}{2}(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${\displaystyle\int}\sqrt{\dfrac{x+{\pi}a}{a\left({\pi}a-x\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$=\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\sqrt{x+{\pi}a}}{\sqrt{{\pi}a-x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Substitute $$u=\dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}a-x}}{\sqrt{x+{\pi}a}}$$
$$\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{1}{-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{{\pi}a-x}\sqrt{x+{\pi}a}}-\frac{\sqrt{{\pi}a-x}}{2\left(x+{\pi}a\right)^\frac{3}{2}}}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

$$=-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{4{\pi}\sqrt{a}}}{\cdot}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\left(u^2+1\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\left(u^2+1\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u=\dfrac{u}{2\left(u^2+1\right)}+\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-6}{\dfrac{1}{2}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{u^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
Can you finish it from here?

Comment: if $-4 \sqrt a \int \frac{1}{(u^2+1)^2} du$ is $= \frac{1}{\sqrt a} \int \sqrt \frac{a\pi+x}{a\pi - x} dx$
 Then the result is: $\frac{u}{2(u^2+1)}+ \frac{tan^{-1}u}{2}$
I'm trying to understand how did you got to that form using "$dx=\frac{1}{...} du$"...

Comment: do the partial factor decomposition But I already did it in the answer for you

Comment: Sorry, I edited the prev comment meanwhile

Comment: just replace all the value like replace dx with $\frac{du}{...}$ and $$u=\dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}a-x}}{\sqrt{x+{\pi}a}}$$ also use this and solve